# bootstrap drop down menu wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a nav bar with a drop down menu but for some reason the drop down menu is not working.I don't know if i linked the JavaScript document right but this is how everyone does it but yet the drop down menu still wont work.

here my code:

```
<head>


<style type="text/css">

body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, fieldset, input, p, blockquote, th, td, iframe {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}


</style>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css.map" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css.map" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css.map" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css.map" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/npm.js"></script>
</head>

<body >




<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">list</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li><a href="" class="choice">Announcements</a></li>

            <li><a href="" class="choice">GetMotivated</a></li>

            <li><a href="" class="choice">Jokes</a></li>


        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Categories <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="" class="choice">LifeProTips</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="choice">TV</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="choice">worldnews</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>


    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


</body>
```

Comment: do you see any errors in the console? - also can you describe: "won't work" a bit more? what's not working?

Comment: You including waaaay too many files.

Comment: You don't need to include `.min.css` and `.css`; they both contain the same thing. Some with `.min.js` and `.js`, `.min.css.map` and `.css.map` (and I don't think you need the `.map` files anyway)

Comment: One more thing, are you sure the files you are including are in the 'css' folder? and the javascript in the 'js' folder?

Comment: Bootstrap requires jQuery: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included

Comment: Basically what Tim is saying is correct. use either the .min.js/css or the .css/js not both. .map files are used for .min files so if you use the .min files then include the maps optionally. Once you do this, if it still doesn't work, then update the code above and we can move forward.

Comment: yeah so removed most of them and kept <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
but it still doesn't work
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: @labue your are the man thanks that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css.map" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css.map" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css.map" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css.map" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

As mentioned in the comments, you don't need to load both the .min and not .min pieces of a file, and you don't need to load .map files at all.

You can switch to using the non-.min versions of files if necessary for debugging.

Comment: i just changed it to this and the drop doesn't  menu still doesn't  drop down

Comment: Added a script for jquery.  Replace that with a local copy - and again, only include the .min or the non .min

Answer (score 0):

all i had to do is include jquery

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and voila it worked